# I want to download a file from cdn using a tag but it is opening file in browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

http://localhost:3000/models/view/6ea6e605-fc3f-4fdd-8778-0066d569d667

this is my file url and i want to download file from using a tag but the file open's in browser

trying to download file from a tag

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: <a
                 as="a"
                    href="http://localhost:3000/models/view/6ea6e605-fc3f-4fdd-8778-0066d569d667"
                    target="_blank"
                    download={`qrcode_${uuid}_nvznar`}
                    
                  >
                   download
                  </a>

Comment: I am trying to download file from a tag as given in above tag but file open's in browser instead of downloading

Comment: what type of file? is it a jpg/pdf/.. ?

Comment: it is an qr code image and the image url is
https://api.nvzn.io/assets/qr/b7d4d587-223c-4f51-8b18-ebc4fbba962a

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are going to download an image following is the way to do it.

```
<a download="filename.jpg" href="/path/to/image" title="ImageName">
    <img alt="ImageName" src="/path/to/image">
</a>
```

And note that `path/to/image` is an important notion here.

Comment: https://api.nvzn.io/assets/qr/b7d4d587-223c-4f51-8b18-ebc4fbba962a
this is my image url which is qr code image

Comment: You can only use the above with the simple websites that you can test.
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-65-deprecations/#block_cross-origin_wzxhzdk5a_download